# How can I use Webview to load a web page in UWP

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

[image]// I want my Application to point to a particular page of a site and display it on webview, I tried this but not working

```
string site = "https://google.com";
myweb.Navigate(new Uri(site));
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
string site = @"https://google.com";
myweb.Navigate(new Uri(site));
```

or

```
myweb.Navigate(new Uri(@"https://www.google.com"));
```

Comment: The font size of the content is smaller than the expectation when using my emulator to test it

Comment: Are you trying to open the WebView on an windows phone or which emulator do you mean?

Comment: @OlayemiRondo maybe ask another question about this, because I dont think that you can handle the font size in a web view...

Comment: On Visual studio 2015, you can test the app with emulator(Looks like windows phone) or the system, when i tested it on the system, the font was very big and ok but when i tested it on the emulator, it was tiny. And the emulator is representing a phone, i will later deploy it to a phone and i think it would be tiny too

Comment: I've attached both images above

Comment: I know, but you have several options there. in which screen resolution are you starting your emulator?

Comment: have u checked the image?

Comment: yep, this looks very fail. but as I said I sadly cannot answer that. Maybe it looks different on a real phone.

Comment: @OlayemiRondo and you may need to create a new question for that. because it is a different problem

Comment: I have created the trend before "How to change the font size of a webview in uwp", but no solution till now

Comment: @OlayemiRondo ok, maybe do you use the same view for the desktop view and for your windows phone emulator?

Comment: Is there a place to change the view?

Comment: There are several ways to seperate the views for each device family. Look at this http://www.igrali.com/2015/08/02/three-ways-to-set-specific-devicefamily-xaml-views-in-uwp/

Comment: @OlayemiRondo i would use method #2

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't show how to manipulate the webview to increase the content on the mobile. it's all about redirection

Comment: If was just an idea. But maybe you need to force the site to load a mobile view of that site. Example: instead of "google.com" try something like "m.google.com"

Comment: Just found a thread about this topic: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5ff914b6-97d2-4e2b-945a-ce7d4eeb4c1d/forcing-webview-to-show-mobile-version?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: Stiil the same thing